# How can I get IAM policies for a GCP service account that is Google-provided?

Tags: gcp, google-iam

I can ask for the details of a service account with

```bash
gcloud iam service-accounts describe <SA-email> --project=<PROJECT>
```

This will give the description, display name, OAuth client, etc.  But it will fail with an error if I try to look for information on default, Google-generated accounts.  For instance,

```bash
gcloud iam service-accounts get-iam-policy <project_number>@cloudbuild.gserviceaccount.com
```

fails with

```bash
ERROR: (gcloud.iam.service-accounts.get-iam-policy) NOT_FOUND: Unknown service account
```

This is true for any `gcloud` action that attempts to peer into a particular service account *that Google auto-generated*.

This is frustrating for us because we have a centralized project that we use for services that we *want* to be shared across our environments, like our Artifact Registry.  We need to give cross-project access to those auto-generated accounts beyond the default values.

We are able to give access, via Terraform or GCP's Config Connector.  But we're not able to *observe* the state in any scriptable way.

Does anyone know how `gcloud` can be used to peer into the workings of *Google auto-generated* service accounts?